# Variable arrays in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, variables

I'm having trouble figureing out my problem. Hopefully you all know if this is possible. I've hit my limits on MS Access and I'm trying to convert my Access modules to run on SQL server.

This is my visual basic code that i'm running:

```
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("select * from ReportFilter")
If rs1.EOF = True Then GoTo nextstep1    
rs1.MoveFirst
a = 0
Do
    b = 0
    RPrim(a, b) = rs1.Fields(0).Value
    b = b + 1
    RPrim(a, b) = rs1.Fields(1).Value
a = a + 1
rs1.MoveNext
If rs1.EOF = True Then GoTo nextstep1
Loop
```

I am unsure, and tried some "googling" to figure out how to do this on SQL server.

The reportfilter table is already populated, i just cannout find a way to populate the variable with the table values.

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the differences between Access and SQL Server is that Access has embedded support for VBA -- i.e. is not just a database but a compact application platform as well.  SQL Server is a more robust, scalable and enterprise-level RDBMS and does not come with and embedded 4GL language like VBA.  I suggest coupling your scaled up SQL Server solution with VB.net (where you can pretty much plug your Access VBA with maybe minor modifications) or go with any other free language (e.g. Perl to be lightweight or Java).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are trying to read the first two columns from the table into an array.  SQL Server does not have arrays.  You are reading into an array in VB.  This has nothing to do with the database, per se.

You can run the original query on SQL Server, and it should work fine.

You may be able to replace subsequent code with a query in the database.

Also, get in the habit of explicitly listing your columns:

```
select <col1>, <col2>
from ReportFilter
```